# Aria-hidden does not hide the element from queries

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, react-testing-library

Why is RTL showing hidden elements as visible?

```
expect(screen.queryByText(/months in operation\?/i)).not.toBeVisible()
```

`Received element is visible: <label aria-hidden="true" for="monthsDropdown" />`

```
expect(screen.queryByText(/months in operation \?/i)).not.toBeInTheDocument()
```

`expected document not to contain element, found <label aria-hidden="true" for="monthsDropdown">Months in operation?</label> instead`

The parent div for this label also has the styles of display: none; visibility: hidden; height: 0;

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The `aria-hidden` attribute only hides the element from `*ByRole` queries.

---

Let's assume we have the following component with two buttons.

```js
const TestComponent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ display: "none", visibility: "hidden", height: 0 }}>
        <button>Hidden Button</button>
      </div>
      <button aria-hidden="true">Aria Hidden Button</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Even though the first element is not visible due to the parent's style, and the second is being excluded from the accessibility tree with `aria-hidden`, they'll both be accessible through `getByText` queries since they're both present in the DOM.

```js
// Both assertions will be pass
expect(screen.getByText("Hidden Button")).toBeInTheDocument();
expect(screen.getByText("Aria Hidden Button")).toBeInTheDocument();
```

However, trying to access them with `getByRole` queries won't be possible as that query looks to the accessibility tree - unless the `hidden` option is passed in the query.

```js
// Will not find the elements
const [hiddenButton, visibleButton] = screen.getAllByRole("button")

// Will return both elements
const [hiddenButton, visibleButton] = screen.getAllByRole("button", { hidden: true })
```

In terms of visibility, the second button is visible while the first one is not.

```js
// Both assertions will be pass
const [hiddenButton, visibleButton] = screen.getAllByRole("button", { hidden: true })
expect(hiddenButton).not.toBeVisible();
expect(visibleButton).toBeVisible();
```

Comment: Great breakdown, thank you! I guess you can't really test visibility of sections that don't have roles (like divs) in this way...

Comment: Not unless you add an explicit role to the element.